# Can you save your session in Julia

Tags: julia

Im very new to Julia and was trying to save my session (all the values, including functions for example) and didnt see any easy way. There seems to be a pretty complete low level write function for ints, floats, arrays, etc.  But it doesnt, for example, write a DataFrames. Is there an easy way to do this or do I need to code all this from scratch?  Im using V0.2.1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried using the iJulia notebook?  This might be useful for what you're describing.  https://github.com/JuliaLang/IJulia.jl

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with [HDF5.jl](https://github.com/timholy/HDF5.jl). I don't know how well it works for functions, but it should work fine for data frames and any other native Julia type.

For functions you want to keep, I would probably just define them in a regular `.jl` file and `include("def.jl")` at the start of the session, for example.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout out the Julia Data Format https://github.com/JuliaIO/JLD.jl

It can both save specific julia types as well as types you created yourself, and has macros to save your entire workspace at once.

Comment: Could you please add few points, because it looks  more like a comment than an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think it can be in Julia Data format (JLD).
https://github.com/JuliaIO/JLD.jl

If you have own data fromat e.g. type model

```
type Model  
  version::String  
  id::String  
  equations::Vector{Equation}  
  coefs::Vector{Matrix}  
end
```

You can save it with command

```
using JLD
save("MODEL.jld", "modelS", model1)
```

and read as

```
pathReport = joinpath(homedir(),".julia/v0.5/foo/test")
m = JLD.load(joinpath(pathReport, "MODEL.jld"))
model2 = m["modelS"]
model2.equations[1].terms[2] == "EX_01"
```